# phpunit failed, gitlab-ci still passed

Tags: phpunit, gitlab-ci

- I use gitlab-ci and gitlab-runner to run phpunit in docker    container.
- When phpunit has error or even if I add `exit 1` in    script, the pipeline still shows build success.
- The picture shows    `sh exited 1` instead of `ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1`.
- What    should I do to exit the job not only sh?

[image]

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: d:latest
stages:
 - test
run_test:
 stage: test
 script:
  - cd src/Test
  - phpunit ../Test
 except:
  - master
  - test
```

Comment: Please share the specific part of your gitlab-ci.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is later you have `sh exited 0`